# Linux dynamic kernel loading with overloading device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi4

I want to make my own protocol driver for my custom made spi board. The platform on which I want to attach it is a raspberry Pi4 with arm32. I want to load it dynamically with an overlay device tree.
I can build the driver file but the following isn't clear:

1. Where should the driver exactly placed? I tried /lib/modules/5.4.79-v7, /lib/modules/5.4.79-v7/build
2. I made in the config.txt an entry dtoverlays= driver.ko and placed the dtbo under /boot/overlays. Is this correct?
3. Can the driver be loaded at runtime without a second reboot after I placed the overlay file in the right folder.
4. Is the driver first loaded if the function "spi_new_device" is called or can it be done in this way?

If I call sudo insmod .ko the driver is loaded with:

```
rpi4: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
```

The probe function isn't called yet.

Comment: `make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=...` will place it where it's correct. **Module initialization** and **device probe** are two separate independent operations (Of course the latter one can't be performed w/o a driver being initialized).

Comment: Do you know where? INSTALL_MOD_PATH variable is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Where should the driver exactly placed? I tried /lib/modules/5.4.79-v7, /lib/modules/5.4.79-v7/build

> Answer: The driver is placed under /lib/modules/5.4.79-v7/extra if it is an extra module and build with.
>
> ```
> make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD modules_install
> ```

2. I made in the config.txt an entry dtoverlays= driver.ko and placed the dtbo under /boot/overlays. Is this correct?

> Answer: It can be done in this way with rpi.

3. Can the driver be loaded at runtime without a second reboot after I placed the overlay file in the right folder.

> Answer: If the driver is installed under extra it is not loaded. Also it is not loaded after reboot. The driver must be loaded with "modprobe" but without the extension ".ko". Modprobe search the driver under lib/modules.